# Plotting in loop hangs matplotlib: strange memory leak?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, crash, time-series

I have a bunch of timestamp-value like pandas.DataFrame -s in a dict, like this:

```
dfS[k1] = df1
dfS[k2] = df2
...
```

While plotting to the same axis like this:

```
dfS[k1].plot(ax=ax1)
dfS[k2].plot(ax=ax1)
...
```

works, the same in a loop:

```
for k in dfS.keys():
    dfS[k].plot(ax=ax1)
```

crashes `matplotlib` after about 20 secs with the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testDataDisplay.py", line 66, in <module>
    dfS[k].plot(ax=ax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 847, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 61, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 269, in generate
    self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 437, in _post_plot_logic_common
    self._apply_axis_properties(ax.xaxis, rot=self.rot, fontsize=self.fontsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 520, in _apply_axis_properties
    labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1207, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1378, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1283, in get_majorticklocs
    return self.major.locator()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py", line 988, in __call__
    locs = self._get_default_locs(vmin, vmax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py", line 968, in _get_default_locs
    self.plot_obj.date_axis_info = self.finder(vmin, vmax, self.freq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py", line 588, in _daily_finder
    info = np.zeros(
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 45.2 GiB for an array with shape (1617786887,) and data type [('val', '<i8'), ('maj', '?'), ('min', '?'), ('fmt', 'S20')]
```

Looks like `matplotlib` interprets a timestamp as a shape, since the ***total*** ***number*** of datapoints is just ***608***. Here is some of it for reference:

```
dfS['pRp:1:avg5min'].head(4)
                 pRp:1:avg5min
2021-04-07 14:14:30        64.6226
2021-04-07 14:14:35        64.1258
2021-04-07 14:14:40        64.5340
2021-04-07 14:14:45        66.2782

for key in dfS.keys():
    print(key, end=' ')
    print(dfS[key].shape)

pRp:0:avg5min (5, 1)
pRp:0:raw (299, 1)
pRp:1:avg5min (5, 1)
pRp:1:raw (299, 1)

matplotlib.__version__
'3.3.0'

python3 --version
Python 3.8.6

pd.__version__
'1.0.5'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that you are into pandas code, not yet in matplotlib.  Could you add the full error trace (as text)?  Did you try to print `dfS[k].head()` and similar debugging? What version of pandas are you running? Did you try to upgrade?

Comment: @JohanC, I've updated the post with data requested except for upgrade, as everything is on a freshly installed, apt-get upgrade-ed host.

Comment: I really think it still makes sense to try the same with the latest matplotlib and pandas versions. Something like `pip install matplotlib pandas --upgrade`. Maybe it doesn't help, but it is always best to run the most recent bug fixes. These projects are developed at a fast pace, with thousands of fixes and extensions per year.

Comment: @JohanC Unfortunately, updating matplotlib, pandas to the latest versions via pip did not solve this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This should rather be a comment then an answer - but because stackoverflow decides that I can only comment with 50 reputation points, I will formulate this as an answer:

It seems that you are loading multiple data frames, each with its own time series  and multiple data columns, and thus hitting the memory limit.

When you perform

```
for k in dfS.keys():
    dfS[k].plot(ax=ax1)
```

you plot the whole dataframe.

Maybe something like this will help you:

```
for k in dfS.keys():
    dfS[k].plot(x="columnName", ax=ax1)
```

Where `columnName` represents the name of a specific column of the dataframe.

It is really hard to guess the exact problem here, because we don't know how the input data looks like - maybe you post a minimal or header version of the data content here.

Comment: it is each a single column with DateTime index.  I have no clue, how to reference the name of the index here,  `dfS[k].index` resolves to a list of timestamps.